# Additional Query depending on boolean

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I have query like that:

```
getData(number: String)

@GET("/myapp/{number}/details")
fun getData(
@Path number: String
)
```

But I would like to create something like:

```
getData(withAdditionalParam: Boolean, number: String)


@GET("/myapp/{number}/details?sometimesAdditionalParam="number")
    fun getData(
    @Path number: String,
    ? what here ?
    )
```

At the moment I have 2 separate GET functions but I belive we can achieve it using 1 get function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the additional param nullable so that Retrofit only passes it if it's not null.

```
@GET("/myapp/{number}/details")
    fun getData(
    @Path number: String,
    @Query("sometimesAdditionalParam") additionalParam : Boolean? = null
    )
```

when you want to pass it

```
getData(number: String, true)
```

when you don't

```
getData(number: String)
```

Comment: i would go a step further and add it as null by default, `@Query("sometimesAdditionalParam") additionalParam : Boolean? = null` so that you DONT have to pass it if it's null, but nothing wrong with your answer obviously, just as an alternative

Comment: Good call @a_local_nobody

Answer (score 2):

**Argument can be annotated with `@Query`**

```
@GET("/myapp/{number}/details")
fun getData(
    @Path("number") number: String,
    @Query("sometimesAdditionalParam") sometimesAdditionalParam: Boolean? = null
)
```

Assigning default null value to query parameter does not append query param `sometimesAdditionalParam` to request